In Nextjs dangerouslySetInnerHTML client and server side mismatch issue
I am using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in NextJs application to load dynamic HTML/Component, it is loading fine but throwing and error on console as shown below in screenshot

So basically on rendering on client side it shows what HTML is written without tags but on server side it is reading with tags, how can I solve this issue?
PS: Dynamic content can be nested as well
I have tried wrapping it into div but does't worked as expected

Does this answer your question? Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div
